# How to check if textField is equal to a string from an array

Tags: swift

I have a list of ATM, each ATM has a name.

Now I want to check if my textField.text is equal to that name of each ATM. Surely, I can do this with for loop like so:

```
for atm in atms {
     if nameTextField.text == atm.name {
         // Do some Stuff
     }
}
```

But the question here is I want another way to archive this.

Any helps would be appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE 1**:

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        if let _ = atms.filter({$0.name == nameTextField.text}).first {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "This name has been added!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if nameTextField.text != "" && addressTextField.text != "" && latitudeTextField.text != "" && longitudeTextField.text != "" {
            saveData()
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Missing Info", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Work now, thanks for the answer.

Comment: There isn't another way to do it. If you have a names array, you could do: `names.contains(nameTextField.text)`

Comment: If I create a names array, I still need a for loop to assign atm's name to each element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if let atm = atms.filter({$0.name == nameTextField.text}).first {
   //Show alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "This name has been added!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
   //do another stuff
}
```

It will check the first atm that matches

Comment: It doesn't present an alert when I type a same name, could you check my update.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. It just check if textfield content is equal to any atm's name. It was what you were asking for, wasn't it?

Comment: po atms.filter({$0.name == nameTextField.text}).first
nil

Comment: Is your `addButtonTapped(sender: UIButton)` called? Have you linked the action correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is called, but I po atms.filter({$0.name == nameTextField.text}).first, it goes nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108591/discussion-between-bigdestroyer-and-khuong291).